# Problem with CORS consuming Spring boot REST API

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, cors, fetch

Good afternoon

I have a react JS application. This app consumes a rest service with spring boot and spring security.

This is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ServiceSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
    {
        try 
        {
            http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
            http.cors();            
           
        }         
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ServiceSecurity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() 
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://192.168.194.129:8080","http://192.168.193.8:8080","http://192.168.193.8:3000","http://192.168.193.6:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("cache-control","Content-Type","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","Access-Control-Allow-Methods","Authorization","X-Requested-With","X-Frame-Options"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","Access-Control-Allow-Methods","Authorization","X-Requested-With","X-Frame-Options"));
        
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues());        
        return source;
    }


}
```

If I enable the chrome extension "Allow cors" I can get all data only if I realize the petition from a valid URL (in the spring security configuration setAllowedOrigins). If I try to get data from another URL, chrome console show me 403 error.

For that reason, I know that my rest service configuration is working.

But, If turn off "Allow cors" chrome extension, I get this error:

`Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.193.8/WebService/obtenerFertilizantes' from origin 'http://192.168.193.8:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://192.168.193.8:3000, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Chrome network log say:
(failed)net::ERR_FAILED fetch

The API is consumed in javascript with fetch:

```
config = {
          method: 'GET',
          crossDomain:true,
          async: true,
          headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password),
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',                    
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Authorization",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":true,
              "cache-control": "no-cache"
          }                
        };
        
        fetch("http://localhost/service/obtenerFertlizantes",config)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            setDatos(responseJson);
          });
```

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: don't put `Access-Control-*` headers in to your request for a start - and stop sending multiple values in access-control-allow-origin ... the error clearly tells you that your server is sending `http://192.168.193.8:3000, *`

Comment: you also don't need to set all those `access-Control-*` values in allowed headers / exposed headers ...

Comment: Thanks for your recomendation. But the error is the same. The new headers is:  headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password),
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }

Comment: I don´t know which part I am sending multiples values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could resolve the problem.

API rest service is over Payara server.
That server had configured an extra CORS in default-web.xml configuration file.

I removed lines regarding CORS configuration and works fine!

I only work with spring security configuration CORS.

Thanks!